# Transaction settings while using Message-Driven-Channel-Adapter and DMLC

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using Message-Driven-Channel-Adapter with DMLC.

```
 Should i set both ?
    1) acknowledge="transacted" in Message-Driven-Channel-Adapter and 
    2) sessionTransacted as true in DMLC

 Or is it enough to set acknowledge="transacted" in Message-Driven-Channel-Adapter alone.
```

When i set acknowledgement in Adapter alone , the performance looks good. But when exception is thrown from error handler, the message is not rolled back.
If I set acknowlegment in both, the performance looks poor but the message rolls back properly

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are injecting a DMLC via the `container` attribute, you must set `sessionTransacted` on the DMLC.